# Electron + Angular 'Not allowed to load local resource' on published version

Tags: angular, electron

I've recently started a project with Electron and Angular and I'm still trying to wrap my head around it.

During development, and starting the application locally (not by running the exe), everything works fine.
However, when I try to run published version of the app (built and by running the exe), I get the infamous error `Not allowed to load local resource`. To be more specific:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: 
file:///C:/Users/Superiom/AppData/Local/Programs/my-app/resources/app.asar/dist/my-app/index.html
```

The `main.js` file opens the initial view:

```
win.loadFile(`dist/my-app/index.html`);
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
"name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "files": [
    "*.js",
    "dist",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng build --aot && electron .",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "electron": "electron .",
    "elProd": "ng build --prod && electron .",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "myApp.test.App",
    "productName": "MyApp",
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2018 Test",
    "win": {
      "icon": "build/jongis.ico",
      "target": "
  }
```

I publish the application by running the `npm run dist` command. This creates the `dist` folder with the .exe file. The problem occurs when I open the application.

I can provide additional information if needed.

I've tried almost everything from proposed and accepted solutions on similar questions here on Stackoverflow, but nothing seems to solve the problem.

Comment: DId you figure this out? I'm running into the same issue.  TIA

Comment: I don't remember exactly what I did. Reading what I've asked in the question and comparing the currently written code, the only change I have is this:


    mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app/index.html`);

Answer (score 0):

Please change `${__dirname}/app/index.html` with `dist/my-app/index.html`, worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22269285)

Comment: Had no indent to critique, revised my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and resolved by solution in following answer in this link:-

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54951636/not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-angular7-electron/76709438#76709438
```

You can also refer to this guide for further clarification:-

https://medium.com/@darediP/packaging-electron-app-c82f41e2d657